# Add and delete rows dynamically in multiple sections

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I have searched and search and i just can´t seem to find an answer to my problem. I have a dynamic tableview with 3 rows (each row is a section) and a edit button at the top right of the tableview. each time the user taps edit it has to be possible to add or delete a row. Everything works except the part when the + button is taped to ad a new row. This is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{

return 3;
}


 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

int count = [myarray count];
if (myarray != nil) count ++;
return count;

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{     

id cell;
switch(indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        if(indexPath.row==0) {
            static NSString *cellType1 = @"cellType1";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellType1];
            return cell;
        }
        break;

    case 1:
        if(indexPath.row==0) {
            static NSString *cellType2= @"cellType2";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellType2];
            return cell;
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        if(indexPath.row==0) {
            static NSString *cellType3= @"cellType3";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellType3];
            return cell;
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
return cell;
}



- (IBAction) EditTable:(id)sender
{
if(self.editing)
{
    [super setEditing:NO animated:NO]; 
    [Table setEditing:NO animated:NO];
    [Table reloadData];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
}
else
{
    [super setEditing:YES animated:YES]; 
    [Table setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    [Table reloadData];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Ok"];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
}
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView         editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

if (self.editing == NO || !indexPath) return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;

if (self.editing && indexPath.row == ([myarray count])) 
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
} else 
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)TableView commitEditingStyle:    (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
{
    [myarray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [Table reloadData];
} else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
{
    switch(indexPath.section) {
        case 0:

             if(indexPath.row==0) {
                static NSString *cellType1 = @"cellType1";
                UITableViewCell *cell = [TableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellType1];
                [arry insertObject:cell atIndex:[myarray count]];
                [Table reloadData];

            }
            break;

        case 1:
            if(indexPath.row==0) {
                static NSString *cellType2= @"cellType2";
                UITableViewCell *cell = [TableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellType2];
                [arry insertObject:cell atIndex:[myarray count]];

            }
            break;

        case 2:
            if(indexPath.row==0) {
                static NSString *cellType3= @"cellType3";
                UITableViewCell *cell = [TableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellType3];
                [arry insertObject:cell atIndex:[myarray count]];

            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

 }
```

As i said before, everything works until i press the + button (that appears on the left side when the edit button is pressed) to add a new row. Then it shows an error: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath.

What am i doing wrong? any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you never actually `+alloc` or `-init` a cell, so `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is most likely returning nil (`-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` doesn't cut it).

Second off,  comparing `indexPath.row` to `[myarray count]` will *never* be true, because arrays and tables may be zero-based, but their counts aren't.

Comment: Hello Codafi. First of all, thanks for answering and looking to my problem. Let me see if i understood: in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method i have to alloc a cell variable correct?. But i don´t understand what i have to do in my TableView commitEditingStyle method. What do you suggest? Thanks

Comment: Well, because cells are reused, we `+alloc` only if the cell is nil (so compare it with an if statement) and in `commitEditingStyle:` your comparisons are wacko.  Just compare to `[myArray count]-1`